# Why can't I import a C# namespace in interactive mode in VS2017?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to import a namespace in interactive mode (the Immediate Window) in VS 2017. However, it doesn't seem to work:

```
using System.Linq
error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'using'
using System.Linq;
error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'using'
#r System.Linq
error CS1525: Invalid expression term ''
#help
error CS1525: Invalid expression term ''
```

I looked at the [Roslyn GitHub wiki](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window) to see if there was a different way to import a namespace in interactive, and I also Googled about my problem. However, I can't find anyone else who had a problem importing namespaces in interactive. Why is this happening, and how can I resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware, that you still can use fully qualified names? `using` is just a shorthand, it doesn't add any new features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only possible in the interactive window, not the immediate window.  See [these](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/wiki/Interactive-Window.md) instructions.

Comment: The link now returns the base page for the Roslyn project (not a specific documentation page).

Answer (score 3):

Use full path to dll

For .Net Framework

```
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\Facades\System.Linq.dll"
```

For .NET Core

```
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.dll"
```

Check file locations and adjust version numbers.

Comment: This also works for ScriptCs (http://scriptcs.net/).